# Excel Column to Gams error

Tags: excel, import

Am having trouble importing data from an excel file and not quite sure what im doing wrong. I need to assign a column of data to data p....

THANKS!

```
$CALL GDXXRW.EXE SHIPS.xls  par=p  rdim=1 rng=B2:B54  skipempty=0

PARAMETER p(r,c) hull number;
$GDXIN p.gdx
$LOAD p
$GDXIN;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way:

```
parameter p(r,c);
$CALL GDXXRW SHIPS.xlsx trace=3 par=p rng=Sheet1!B2:B54 rdim=1 cdim=1
$gdxin SHIPS.gdx
$load p
$gdxin
```

Mine didn't work until I have put dimensions at the end. Additionally, I think .gdx needs to have the same name as .xls file. Also, check if the extension of Excel file is .xls or .xlsx. If these two don't match it won't work.